# Важно ли для RAID 0 что бы у дисков совпадал кэш?

Tags: сервер, железо, хранение-данных, hdd

Здравствуйте, есть два диска с кэшем 16mb и 32mb (оба WD/7200rpm/500gb), будут ли они корректно работать в RAID 0?

Использовать такую конфигурацию буду для домашних нужд. Контроллер встроен в материнскую плату.
Спасибо за внимание.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет, это не важно. Использование кеша - внутреннее дело современных жестких дисков. Размер кеша никак не касается контроллера.